# Example of a function $f(x,t)$ defined on $X \times (0,T)$ that is in $L^p(X)$ for all $1 \leq p \leq \infty$ but not in $L^q(0, T; L^p)$?

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, bochner-spaces

Let $f(x,t)$ be defined on some space $X \times (0, T)$ and suppose for all time $t$, $f(t) \in L^p(X)$. I am trying to think of an example where $f \not\in L^q(0, T; L^p)$.

By definition we have
$$\|f\|_{L^q(0, T; L^p)} = \Big(\int_0^T \|f\|_{L^p(X)}^q\Big)^{(1/q)}$$
and so
$$\Big(\int_0^T \|f\|_{L^p(X)}^q d\mu(t) \Big)^{(1/q)} \leq \Big(\max_{t \in (0,t)} \|f(t)\|_{L^p(X)}^q \int_0^T d\mu(t)\Big)^{(1/q)} \\= \mu(0,T)^{(1/q)} \max_{t \in (0,t)} \|f(t)\|_{L^p(X)}^q$$
and since $(0,T)$ has finite measure and $f(t) \in L^p(X)$ for all $t$, then is finite but this seems like a strange and incorrect result since it would imply if the if $f \in L^p$ then it is in $L^q(0, T; L^p)$ for all $q > 0$.

Is there an example of a function that is in $L^p$ for all $1 \leq p \leq \infty$ but not in $L^q(0, T; L^p)$?

Comment: I think your outer integral in the definition of the mixed norm should be $\int_0^T$ instead of $\int_X$. The point of the inequality you derive is that if $f(t)\in L^p(X)$ **uniformly** in time, i.e. $\sup_t \| f(t)\|_{L^p}<\infty$, then your function is in the mixed $L^q(0,T;L^p)$. The counterexample could be something like $t^{-1/q}f(x)$ where $f\in L^p(X)$.

Comment: @Jose27 Thank you for your comment and catching that typo, I have corrected my post. So if $f(t) \in L^p(X)$ uniformly in time then $f \in L^q(0, T; L^p)$ for all $q \geq 1$? In other words, the result I derived only holds if we know that $f \in L^\infty(0, T; L^p)$?

Comment: Exactly, and that result you proved is the vector-valued analogue of $L^\infty(Y)\subset L^q(Y)$ for any finite measure space $Y$. In this case $Y=(0,T)$ with Lebesgue measure, but now your functions have values in the Banach space $L^p(X)$.

Comment: @Jose27 Thank you for your comments!